# Best approach to find conditional means based on category and sliding date range

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, optimization

| Date | Category | X-Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ... | Red | 12 |
| ... | Blue | 19 |
| ... | ... | ... |

Given a Pandas data frame like the above, how can I most efficiently calculate for each row, the sum X-Value of all rows [in the same Category AND with dates +- 14 days either side of the row I am on]?

My data set is 500,000 rows long.

The methods I've tried consider the whole data set for every row, which is slow for frames above a few 1,000 rows.

If I consider e.g. category & calendar month I can speed it up, but I want a kind of sliding window which changes with each row, rather than fixed calendar months.

```
def cohort_value(row):
    row_date = row['date']
    window_start_date = row_date - timedelta(days=14)
    window_end_date = row_date + timedelta(days=14)
    
    cohort_value = df[(df['date'] > start_date) & (df['date'] < end_date)]['value'].sum()
    
    return  cohort_value

df.apply(cohort_value, axis=1)
```

Comment: `for x in pd.unique(df['category']):
df_partial = df[df['category'] == x]
cpax.append(df_partial.apply(cohort_value, axis=1))`

This completes in 6 minutes, I'm looking for anything faster.

Answer (score 0):

Using a small dataframe with the same structure as example:

```
data = {
    "Date": pd.date_range(start="2024-03-01", periods=5),
    "Category": ["Red", "Red", "Red", "Blue", "Red"],
    "X-Value": [12, 19, 15, 22, 18],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

```
        Date Category  X-Value
0 2024-03-01      Red       12
1 2024-03-02      Red       19
2 2024-03-03      Red       15
3 2024-03-04     Blue       22
4 2024-03-05      Red       18
```

If you set the `Date`as index, you can group by `Category`, calculate rolling windows and sum the values in each. In the example below I'm using 3-day windows (`window="3D"`), which you can change to 29 if you want the 14 before and 14 after each row.

```
df_rolling = (
    df.set_index("Date")
    .groupby("Category")["X-Value"]
    .rolling(window="3D", center=True)
    .sum()
    .reset_index(name="rolling_sum")
)

df = pd.merge(df, df_rolling, how="left")
```

```
        Date Category  X-Value  rolling_sum
0 2024-03-01      Red       12         31.0
1 2024-03-02      Red       19         46.0
2 2024-03-03      Red       15         34.0
3 2024-03-04     Blue       22         22.0
4 2024-03-05      Red       18         18.0
```